# Eclipse CVS project disconnected from repository and cannot be reconnected

Tags: eclipse, cvs

I have updated my eclipse to the ~last version (2019-03) and I have opened a projet that is normally connected to cvs.
But, when I have opened it, I didn't have intalled CVS in the new eclise, but Git was installed.
So, When I wanted to commit, using "team>commit" contextual menu, I realized that it was the git "team" menu (git that I don't use with eclipse).

So, I delete the git plugins and installed the CVS plugin.

But, I can't connect my project anymore. Now, in the "Team" menu, I only have "Apply path" submenu and not "share" to connect to my CVS.

I tried to open an other closed project that was connected to CVS (after having installed the CVS plugin) and this project is well connected.

So, I think it was because of git my projet was disconnected.

I have remove the .gitignore file of my project, and still have my "CVS" folders in each of my folders.

Any idea of how to reconnect my project ?

Thanks all !